# calculate group count, sum for a given date using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having a table that stores data on invoices. Once its been paid `is_paid` will be marked as 1

So what im tryin to do is get all the unpaid invoices `(where is_paid =0)` for each user for a given date, along with the total pending amount for each employee and the count of pending invoices for that period

```
SELECT
              receivable.amount,
              receivable.admission,
receivable.grouped,
              receivable.month,
              emp.name
            FROM
              receivable JOIN students ON receivable.emp_id = emp.id
where receivable.is_paid='0' 
group by receivable.emp_id
ORDER BY CAST(receivable.grouped AS UNSIGNED ) , receivable.grouped
```

How do I change the above code to calculate the count of pending invoices for the given period, sum of pending amount for each user and the total of grouped for that period (user enters the date so the records needs to be shown everything before that including that date)

Below is the report structure

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you clarify what are `grouped`, `admission`, and `month` in the receivable table?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that `month` refers to the first of the month - if you can clarify this point I can write up something more accurate.  Essentially, you need to use the SUM and COUNT aggregate functions, and declare every other column to be returned as part of the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT
  receivable.emp_id,
  emp.name,
  receivable.grouped,
  receivable.month,
  SUM(receivable.amount) as totalAmount
  COUNT(*) as totalCount
FROM receivable 
JOIN emp ON receivable.emp_id = emp.id
WHERE receivable.is_paid='0'
  AND receivable.month = '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY receivable.emp_id, emp.name, receivable.grouped, receivable.month
ORDER BY CAST(receivable.grouped AS UNSIGNED ), receivable.grouped
```